# template programming vectors C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector

`template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector; // generic template`

The template for the vector class is defined as above. After some research, the `class Alloc` is used to identify a memory storage model. What are the possible values I can pass to it, i.e.:

are `vector <int, double> v1;` or `vector <int, int>` allowed?

Comment: A `double` or `int` is unlikely to constitute a valid `Alloc` parameter type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, it's not unlikely, it isn't.

Comment: @NeilKirk Well of course! I think that was just an attempt to give a _polite_ hint ;) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any class that implements the [allocator interface](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/).